# Proof of $(A-B) \cup (B-A) = (A-C) \cup (C-A)$ then $B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know intuitively that if $(A-B) \cup (B-A) = (A-C) \cup (C-A)$ then $B=C$. But it just seems hard to prove it without using a pictorial argument. Can anyone show how I may proceed?

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $x$ is an element that is in $B$ but not in $A$. Then $$x\in B-A=B\cap A^c$$ and therefore $$x \in (A-B)\cup (B-A)$$ Due to the given equality we must also have that $$x \in (A-C)\cup (C-A)$$ but since $x \notin A$ by assumption we have that $$x \in C-A$$ or $x \in C$. The same holds for every element in $C$ witht that property, so that we have that $$B\cap A^c =C \cap A^c\tag1$$ Assume know that $y$ is an element that lies in $B$ and in $A$, that is $y \in A \cap B$. Then, this element is not included in the set on LHS and therefore (due to the given equality) it is also not included in the set on the RHS. Repeating for $C$, we conclude also that $$B\cap A=C \cap A\tag2$$ Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ with the fact that $$B=(B\cap A) \cup (B\cap A^c)$$ and similarly for $C$, we have that $B=C$ as required.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof.

The problem statement contains two expressions of the form $\;(A \setminus X) \cup (X \setminus A)\;$.  Let's first try to simplify those.  Which elements $\;x\;$ are members of such a set? Let's calculate:

\begin{align}
& x \in (A \setminus X) \cup (X \setminus A) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cup\;$; definition of $\;\setminus\;$, twice"} \\
& (x \in A \land x \not\in X) \lor (x \in X \land x \not\in A) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& x \in A \;\not\equiv\; x \in X \\
\end{align}

If that second step is not immediately obvious, here is a detailed proof:
\begin{align}
& (P \land \lnot Q) \lor (Q \land \lnot P) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"DeMorgan -- so that we can introduce $\;\Rightarrow\;$ later"} \\
& \lnot ((\lnot P \lor Q) \land (\lnot Q \lor P)) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"$\;\lnot \phi \lor \psi\;$ is one way to write $\;\phi \Rightarrow \psi\;$"} \\
& \lnot ((P \Rightarrow Q) \land (Q \Rightarrow P)) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify: mutual implication is equivalence"} \\
& \lnot (P \equiv Q) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify"} \\
& P \not\equiv Q \\
\end{align}

Now we can simplify
\begin{align}
& (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \;=\; (A \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus A) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"set extensionality; the first calculation above, twice} \\
& \qquad \phantom{\text{"}}\text{-- note that $\;\equiv\;$ and $\;\not\equiv\;$ are associative, and mutually associative,} \\
& \qquad \phantom{\text{"}}\text{therefore we can leave out the parentheses"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \not\equiv x \in B \;\equiv\; x \in A \not\equiv x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: $\;\equiv\;$ is symmetric"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \not\equiv x \in A \;\equiv\; x \in B \not\equiv x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: simplify using the fact that $\;\phi \not\equiv \phi\;$ is false"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B \equiv x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"set extensionality"} \\
& B = C \\
\end{align}

That completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at it: define the symmetric difference $A \oplus B = (A-B) \cup (B-A)$. This defines a (commutative) group operation on all subsets of the universe set, where every set  is its own inverse and $\emptyset$ is the neutral element. Your statement is then $A \oplus B = A \oplus C \rightarrow B = C$, which follows because we cancel by adding $A$ to both sides...

Comment: I think this is cheating. The symmetric difference is not a group operation by definition, and using the fact that it's a group operation amounts to assuming this result. (In fact, proving $\oplus$ is associative, which you need in your solution, is much harder than proving the OP's result!)

Comment: @CliveNewstead Well, $\chi_{A \oplus B} = \chi_A \oplus \chi_B$, where we use pointwise xor in the characteristic functions. This is easily shown (few cases for $x$). So it's just the product $\{0,1\}^U$ with pointwise addition/xor.

Comment: Sure, but it's still a nontrivial result that requires proof -- once you've proved $\chi_{A \oplus B} = \chi_A \oplus \chi_B$ you've only reduced the problem proving that $\oplus$ is associative on $\{0,1\}^U$, but *that* still requires proof. It seems unnecessary to introduce characteristic functions when the original result can be proved directly without much hassle. I'm not trying to slate your answer, it's definitely slick; my comments are mostly for the OP's benefit because there are a lot of unproved assumptions until you do (relatively) a lot more work.

Comment: Granted. But I hoped it might make the result more "intuitive" if seen in that light. If you're just starting set theory it's certainly not an optimal proof..